# DateLastModified earlier than DateCreated

Tags: vba, excel, date, file-attributes

I created a files structure report with Excel using VBA. The files being analyzed are Excel files. I use [`DateCreated` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264090.aspx) and [`DateLastModified` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251660.aspx). In a sample of 60k files, around half of them appear to be modified earlier than created - `DateLastModified` is less than `DateCreated`. The biggest difference is around 7,6 year:

- created at 2012-02-09  11:05:46.
- last modified at 2004-06-29  10:02:00

The entire directory containing the files have been moved between local drives and network drives a few times in the past.

My conclusion is - **`DateCreated` gets updated when file is moved to another location. Is that correct?**

I also thought that if `DateCreated` gets updated when file is moved, then perhaps `DateLastModified` does too. So I have several files that were moved on a certain date and not touched since then. Unexpectedly, all of them have `DateLastModified` earlier than `DateCreated`.

In conclusion, when a file is moved from one location to another, its `DateCreated` property gets updated and `DateLastModified` remains not changed. Why is that? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: I suspect it should be the other way around. `dateCreated` should theoretically be set only once, the moment the record was persisted, or told to persist - while `dateLastModified` can be arbitrarily updated whenever the data model itself has been altered. To put a finer point on it, there should never be a case where the `dateCreated` occurs AFTER the `lastDateModified`

Comment: I would get a second opinion on this as it is very curious. Check the properties of the strange file (right click it in Windows Explorer) and confirm your code result. Even better screenshot it.